# Where did the moral-civil-ceremonial distinction of Old Testament laws come from and when was it popularized?

Tags: old-testament, mosaic-law

When answering this question: [How many laws from Old Testament are still valid in New Testament?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/14472/how-many-laws-from-old-testament-are-still-valid-in-new-testament) I was reminded that my answer is not Biblically derived in making the trinary distinction of Old Testament Laws described below:

> **Ceremonial Law:** This type of law relates to Israel's worship. (Lev 1:1-13) The laws pointed forward to Jesus Christ and were no longer necessary after Jesus' death and resurrection. Though we are no longer bound to them, the principles behind the ceremonial laws, that is to worship and love God, still apply.
>   **Civil Law:** This law dictated Israel's daily living (Deut 24:10-11); but modern society and culture are so radically different that some of these guidelines cannot be followed specifically. The principles behind the commands are used to guide our conduct.
>   **Moral Law:** The moral laws are direct commands of God. A good example are the Ten Commandments (Ex 20:1-17). The moral laws reveal the nature and will of God, and still apply to us today. We do not obey this moral law as a way to obtain salvation, but to live in ways pleasing to God.

To the ancient Jews they were all the same and the Bible makes no apparent distinctions among any of them.

First, does this view have a name? That would make things easier. Now I wonder where did this distinction come from and when was it popularized (because I suspect it is a very old)?

Please do not provide biblical support for this view in your answers unless there is an actual distinction somewhere. I only want to know where it came from and when it was popularized.

Comment: this question has been asked before. http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/154/what-is-the-origin-of-the-tripartite-division-of-the-law?rq=1

Comment: @Mike I see, now, but I don't like that answer.

Comment: @fredsbend you're welcome to proffer a new answer, or place a bounty on the old question.